# Clear network and console log on every click or fetch request on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a website that use `fetch` to navigate, the problem is the `Preserve log` option in developer tools (`network` and `console`) because only works with regular click requests, then I can not clear my network logs as a regular navigation.

There are any way to clear `network` logs capturing every click and executing an script before get the new `fetch` content?

Something like this but adding also network clear:

```js
window.onclick = () => console.clear();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Press the second button in devtools toolbar on the network panel to clear all requests. It's the only method. There's no way to invoke it from a page javascript.

Comment: Yes, these is the way that I'm doing now. Thanks.